# Meteor Velocity/Jasmine fails to start Karma through proxy

Tags: testing, meteor, proxy, jasmine

I am attempting to test a meteor application using Jasmine built on Velocity. When I test the application behind our corporate proxy, Karma does not start, the tests don't run, and I get this error in my Jasmine logs:

```
stream error Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301
```

Presumably because it cannot connect to Karma.

I have tried this outside of our intranet (with no proxy), and it works just fine. Unfortunately, it isn't really feasible to run tests outside of our network.

Is there a setting that I am missing that would make this work?

Edit:
I have answered my own question just in case it is helpful to anyone who is having the same problem, but I'm open to other solutions. I will accept another solution if it solves this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the best way to handle this, but I have gotten karma to launch and the tests to run by unsetting my http proxy environment variable (setting it to "" also works).

```
$ unset HTTP_PROXY
$ meteor
```

or start meteor with an inline env variable

`$ HTTP_PROXY="" meteor`

Comment: This solved my issue as well, but the only error was in the meteor console, (STDERR) [sanjo:karma]: start request failed { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }